# How to specify the Network Directory in the ODBC connection string?

Tags: c#, odbc, paradox

I have configured a DSN for my Paradox database and it works when no other application is using the database, however when there is another app running then I get the error Directory is controlled by another .NET file, even though all applications are configured to use the same Network Directory.

Because of this, I want to try and connect to the database using just a connection string in my application, and I would like to know how to specify the network directory.

Thanks in advance.

I found out how to do this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/initializing-the-paradox-database-driver-HP001032165.aspx

However, my app still reports the error. This is very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a nightmare to track down, but it looks like the cause is that the Windows ODBC always sets the NETDIR in UPPERCASE. I was able to ask my colleague to supply his program using the NETDIR in the same format and this resolved the issue. Wow.